# Вызов игровой функции через указатель непосредственно на память

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Сразу прошу строго не судить, на C++ пишу 3-й день, ранее сидел на C#, Java и Python.

Пытаюсь вызвать игровую функцию через `__stdcall`.

Код:

```
void GameText(const char* szText, int iTime, signed int iStyle)
{
    typedef void(__stdcall* GameText_t)(const char*, int, signed int);
    GameText_t pGameText = (GameText_t)(phandle + 0x9C2C0);
    return pGameText(szText, iTime, iStyle);
}
```

Выдает ошибку(ругается на то, что в `(GameText_t)(phandle + 0x9C2C0)` я передал `phandle`):

> E0852 выражение должно представлять собой указатель на полный тип
>   объекта

Как сделать из `phandle`'a полноценный объект?...

Как можно вызвать функцию игры через `phandle` или через ещё что-то?

Чтение `int` из процесса таким образов работает прекрасно:

```
int Read_Int(int address) {
    int value;

    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, &value, sizeof(value), 0);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Что такое `phandle` и к чему оно здесь вообще? Компилятор говорит вам, что выражение `phandle + 0x9C2C0` некорректно. Что вы хотели сказать этим выражением?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы пытаетесь вломиться в сторонний процесс и что-то там вызвать. Вам стоит для начала пройти ликбез по таким вещам как процесс, поток, адресное пространство.

Comment: Даже если вы узнаете адрес функции, вызвать ее просто так не получится. (Как минимум из-за [вот этой вещи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).) Вообще, зачем вам это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть у меня подозрение, что `phandle` у вас имеет тип `void*`, к которому неприменимо выражение адресной арифметики типа `phandle + 0x9C2C0`. Попробуйте так -

```
((char*)phandle + 0x9C2C0)
```

Но учтите - я ограничиваюсь только пояснением, почему не компилируется конкретно этот текст, и не пытаюсь разбираться, будет ли он корректно работать :) В Visual C++ это компилируется. Везде ли сработает `__stdcall` - думаю, зависит от компилятора.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Смущает также возврат `void` :) -

```
return pGameText(szText, iTime, iStyle);
```

Comment: В возврате `void` нет ничего плохого

Comment: @int3 А смысл? Это не шаблон, тут точно известно, что возвращается `void`. Кстати, я не писал, что это ошибка, заметим - я написал, что это смущает...